# PHP PG imagline() angle?

Tags: php, image, gd, angle

I want to ask you how to add angle system to imageline().
I have an Orange line at (-12, 4) in the following picture.
[image]
How i can make it in 37 degree for example ?

Answer (score 1):

Apply basic trigonometry, using [`sin`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sin.php) and/or [`cos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cos.php).

For a line segment originating at (-12, 4), having a 37 degree slope and terminating at (0, y) you can calculate y with

```
$y = 4 + 12 * tan(pi() * 37 / 180);
```

For a segment of length 12 from (-12, 4) with a 37 degree slope the terminating coordinates are

```
$x = -12 + 12 * cos(pi() * 37 / 180);
$y = 4 + 12 * sin(pi() * 37 / 180);
```

The formula `PI * deg / 180` converts [degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28angle%29) to [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) (this is necessary because trigonometric functions always operate on radians).

Comment: can i make it same position with degree 37?
Example 180+degree

Comment: imageline($physics, $x, $y, $x2, $y2 + $degree, color);
can i make some thing like this ?

Comment: @Bahaazahika: No. Operating on cartesian coordinates (x and y) means that you have to use trig functions whenever angles are involved. It's basic geometry.

Comment: @Bahaazahika: I think it would be more beneficial to everyone if your questions are answered publicly.

Comment: im coding a class we should do some tests then we will release it